# Inno Setup "Unknown Publisher"

Tags: installation, setup

Im using Inno Setup and I have this line in my script:

```
AppPublisher=My Company, Inc.
AppPublisherURL=http://www.example.com/
```

For some reason, it still activates smartscreen "Unknown Publisher." Any ideas as to how to get that to stop? Thanks!

Comment: You have to use a certificate.  Otherwise anyone could claim to be your company

Comment: @Ramhound How do I get one then?

Comment: https://www.digicert.com/code-signing/ Is one of many options